# I accidentally installed the oil filter for the 2.5L version of my 2.0L engine. Will it still work?

Tags: oil, oil-change, oil-filter

I accidentally installed the oil filter for the 2.5L version of my 2.0L engine. Will it still work? I installed the [Fram 6607](https://www.fram.com/parts-search/XG6607/?ref=NoIg5gpgdhBOCGAbEAaKBXRiUgEwAZ8AWVEAZXQCN5Z1SBJAWwAdYIAveUgCSIAJcAOgCsAGVKiAlmAAWAFz4ARdHICepAFQgAukA) instead of [Fram 3593A](https://www.fram.com/parts-search/XG3593A/?ref=NoIg5gpgdhBOCGAbEAaKBXRiUgEwAZ8AWVEAZXQCN5Z1SBJAWwAdYIAveUgCSIAJcAOnwAZUiICWYABYAXPgBF0sgJ6kAVCAC6QA). Will this be okay to drive with?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you started the engine yet? Did it fit up? Was the o-ring the same size as the original? What did you see which was different between the two (you probably didn't notice until you got the new one on I bet). For the most part, a filter is a filter. If it fits/seals, there shouldn't be an issue (especially concerning it's for an engine of the same manufacturer). Just my thinking, though ... I could be wrong.

Comment: Looking at the specs, the o-ring is a little different' between the two, but there isn't that much difference. The new filter is larger than the old one which isn't a problem at all. The new filter also has a slightly higher bypass than the old one (13 v 12), but it really doesn't state what that means (ie: is this PSI or what?). Inside and outside diameter of the o-ring is about 1/8" difference ... most likely it should seal without an issue (oil filter seal land should be much wider than either). As long as it doesn't leak, my "thinking" is it should be okay, but only my opinion.

Comment: I started it up and drove it for about 30 seconds. No leaks, no problems. I think I will drive with the different filter for now.

Comment: You might get away with it, but from the specs the full width of the gaskets are 0.285 and 0.297 inches, but with the wrong size you have an overlap of only 0.156 which is close to half as much. That could be a recipe for a leak later on even if it is OK when new. Putting double the clamping pressure on half the width of the seal might cause problems later as well.

Comment: Given the cost of the correct filter and the cost of a new engine, I know what I would do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have like 1/2 overlap it most likely will work, however new filter is not that expensive, it's not worth the risk. Replace the filter to be safe.